# windows 10 share not accessible from same client with domain admin account

Tags: security, windows-10, share

On a Windows 10 client I have a shared folder with full folder and share access for the local admin group (which is member of the domain admin group).

I have an account that is member of the domain admin group and can access the share from a remote domain client without problems. But when I try to access the share from the the client the share was created, I cannot access it unless I add the local user group to the share security setting. Does anyone know why?

Comment: So only entities that are allowed to access it by the security settings can access it?

Comment: `On a Windows 10 client I have a shared folder with full folder and share access for the local admin group (which is member of the domain admin group).` - You have that backwards. You can't add a local account to a domain group.

Comment: I log in with the same domain admin account on all machines, so shouldn't I have access to the share no matter if I try to access it from remote or local?